# Make an INSERT statement out of result set

Tags: sql, mysql, clickhouse

I have an SQL script, which returns the data from a Clickhouse table in amount of ~23k rows. I want to insert that exact data into a table in MySQL. Since they're two different DBs and there's no proxy to use (so no `INSERT INTO SELECT`), seems that the only option i'm left with is to make an insert script with the exact data i have so i can copy-past it and run on another DB.

In another words, let's say i have a script

```
SELECT date, name, sumIf(events>0) ev
FROM t1
GROUP BY date, name
```

which returns the data

```
2023-10-31  'George'    1261169
2023-11-01  'Alan'      1261370
2023-11-02  'Peter'     1261361
```

How can i modify my script so it returns something like

```
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (2023-10-31, 'George', 1261169), (2023-11-01, 'Alan', 1261370), (2023-11-02, 'Peter', 1261361);
```

?

Comment: You need to write a program in a language that can connect to both databases.

Comment: I'd dump the result set to some kind of CSV or TSV file, then import to MySQL with [mysqlimport](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlimport.html). 23k rows is not too great a volume of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the code that generates needed insert statement

```
select concat('INSERT INTO t2 VALUES ', substring(tmp, 2, length(tmp) - 2))
from (
         select replaceAll(toString(groupArray(concat('(', toString(date), ',', name, ',', toString(sum), ')'))), '\'', '') as tmp
         from (
                      (select toDate('2023-10-31') as date, 'George' as name, 1261169 as sum)
                      union all
                      (select toDate('2023-11-01') as date, 'Alan' as name, 1261370 as sum)
                      union all
                      (select toDate('2023-11-02') as date, 'Peter' as name, 1261361 as sum)
                  ) as t
         ) as t2
```

Output:

```
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (2023-10-31,George,1261169),(2023-11-01,Alan,1261370),(2023-11-02,Peter,1261361)
```

You may use clickhouse playground to test things:
https://play.clickhouse.com/play?user=play#c2VsZWN0IDE=

Unfortunately there is not arrayFold function in playground for some reason, this function may simplify code, but I made an ad-hoc solution with string manipulations

Comment: Just a note: to insert date string into MySQL, it has to be wrapped in quotes. Otherwise it's not parsed correctly

Answer (score 0):

There is a more elegant method for this.

```sql
SELECT date, name, sumIf(events>0) ev
FROM t1
GROUP BY date, name
FORMAT SQLInsert
SETTINGS 
  output_format_sql_insert_max_batch_size = 3,
  output_format_sql_insert_table_name = 't2'
```

The output will be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES 
  (2023-10-31, 'George', 1261169), 
  (2023-11-01, 'Alan', 1261370), 
  (2023-11-02, 'Peter', 1261361);
```

**Bonus**

You can create a link between your ClickHouse and MySQL instance and directly insert data into MySQL using MySQL table engine:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t2
(
    ...
)
ENGINE = MySQL('localhost:3306', 'test', 'test', 'bayonet', '123');

INSERT INTO t2
SELECT date, name, sumIf(events>0) ev
FROM t1
GROUP BY date, name
```